# Каким изменить таблицу mssql и обратиться к ней в 1м наборе запросов?

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

Собственно есть временная таблица. 
Есть процедура, которая изменяет ее, добавляя поля в структуру таблицы.

Текст процедуры.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ClearTable]
AS
BEGIN

   if object_id('tempdb..#tmp_contracts') is not null
      truncate table #tmp_contracts;   

   declare @field varchar(max), @table varchar(max);
   declare field_cursor cursor for
   select '[' + name +']',
          case object_id  
            when Object_ID('tempdb..#tmp_contracts') then '#tmp_contracts'
            else '' end
      from tempdb.sys.columns
   where name !='Договор' and
        object_id = Object_ID('tempdb..#tmp_contracts') or

   open field_cursor;
   fetch next from field_cursor into  @field, @table;
   while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
      exec( 'alter table ' + @table + ' drop column  ' + @field );
      fetch next from field_cursor into @field, @table;
   end
   close field_cursor;
   deallocate field_cursor;

   declare @body nvarchar(max) = '';
   /*#tmp_contracts*/
   if object_id('tempdb..#tmp_contracts') is not null begin      
      set @body += 'alter table #tmp_contracts add  [Свод0]             int;'
      set @body += 'alter table #tmp_contracts add  [Отделение]         int;'
      set @body += 'alter table #tmp_contracts add  [Участок]           int;'
      set @body += 'alter table #tmp_contracts add  [Продавец]          int;'
      set @body += 'alter table #tmp_contracts add  [Грузоотправитель]  int;'
   end

   exec sp_executesql @body;

END
```

и есть другая процедура, которая нужна для заполнения даннной таблицы.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_contracts] @root int
AS
BEGIN

 /*В процедуре более сложная логика с разворачиванием иерархии и добавлением данных, для примера простой инсерт*/
      insert into #tmp_contracts ( Договор, Свод0, Отделение, Участок, Продавец, Грузоотправитель )
      select row_id, -1, -1, -1, -1
        from dbo.Договор 
       where row_Id = @root;

END
```

и есть некая табличка например договор, с идентификатором row_id, которую джойним к нашей временной таблице.

Пример использования:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tmp_contracts') is not null drop table #tmp_contracts;
create table #tmp_contracts( Договор int );

exec dbo.usp_cleartable;
exec dbo.usp_contracts 123456;

select  * from #tmp_contracts f
join dbo.Договор dog on dog.row_id = f.Отделение
```

При подобном обращении, в первом вызове процедуры, и модификации таблицы, sql ругается на отсутствие колонок. Но если поставить "go" после вызова процедуры все работает.Если обернуть запрос в exec '', то тоже все работает.

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что данное действие хотелось бы выполнять в одной транзакции, без применения go и оборачивания запроса в строку.  Есть ли способ, как-то обновить данные структуры таблицы внутри запроса, или-же в самой процедуре, после ее выполнения?

Comment: Дак процедура выполняется. Если сделать простой селект - то все ок.

Comment: *данное действие хотелось бы выполнять в одной транзакции, без применения go и оборачивания запроса в строку* - речь о транзакции или всё-таки о батче?

Comment: То, что вы называете "транзакцией" - не транзакция, а батч (batch) - просто набор запросов, отправляемых на сервер одной пачкой. Если первый запрос батча пройдет, а второй упадет с ошибкой выполнения - то результат первого запроса не откатился, как вы этого ожидаете. Если вам нужна именно транзакция - явно пропишите begin transaction/commit в коде.

Comment: @PashaPash Да согласен, это batch. Но есть ли какой-то способ обратиться в рамках одного набора запросов к созданной таблице? Дело в том, что, даже если дропать таблицу каждый раз, но в одной из попыток получить данные, написать просто `select * from #tmp_contracts`, то последующие попытки выполнить выше указанный запрос, пройдут без ошибок. Т.к. каким-то образом запомнилась структура данной таблицы...

Comment: @Stonum используйте табличные переменные вместо таблиц - не будет проблем с парсингом в пределах батча

Comment: @PashaPash - тут похоже ещё и с `@@NESTLEVEL`  напутано (см. комментарии к моему ответу). Автор постоянно упоминает какую-то `usp_contracts`. Кажется вопрос требует правки

Comment: @Anatol  - добавил пример использования обоих процедур, которые упоминал.

Comment: @Stonum - Что ж Вы описание не изменили? Опять какие-то транзакции и прочая путаница

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что всё можно сделать гораздо проще.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_contracts') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp_contracts;

SELECT 1 AS Договор,
       123 AS Свод0,
       12345 AS Отделение,
       123456 AS Участок,
       99999 AS Продавец,
       88888 AS Грузоотправитель
INTO #tmp_contracts;

SELECT *
FROM #tmp_contracts f
     JOIN dbo.Договор dog ON dog.row_id = f.Отделение;
```

Ну и, насколько я понимаю, процедура `dbo.usp_cleartable` не нужна.

Comment: Процедура нужна для удобства очистки таблиц.
Пример использования. dbo.usp_contracts как-раз таки заполняет таблицу, и так-же может расширить ее по необходимости.

`exec dbo.usp_cleartable;
exec dbo.usp_contracts -10;
          
select * from #tmp_contracts f
join dbo.Договор d on d.row_id = f.Отделение`

Comment: @Stonum В ответе использована техника динамического формирования структуры временной таблицы исходя их данных, возвращаемых запросом. С использованием такой техники нет необходимости заранее создавать таблицу с указанием её структуры. Поэтому нет необходимости вручную её чистить и формировать. Про `usp_contracts` речи вообще не было, ни в вопросе, ни в ответе.

Comment: Если я этот код выполню внутри процедуры `usp_contracts` которая как раз заполняет таблицу данными, я так понимаю, потеряю видимость ее снаружи процедуры?

Comment: `create procedure dbo.usp_clear
as begin
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_contracts') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp_contracts;

 SELECT 1 AS Договор,
       123 AS Свод0,
       12345 AS Отделение,
       123456 AS Участок,
       99999 AS Продавец,
       88888 AS Грузоотправитель
INTO #tmp_contracts;
end

create table #tmp_contracts( Договор int );
exec usp_clear
select * from #tmp_contracts`
в данном случае таблица уже не видна, т.к. создана внутри процедуры

Answer (score 0):

Немного подправлю ответ Anatol, очевидно записей во временную таблицу будет вставляться несколько, тогда лучше переписать как-то так:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp_contracts') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp_contracts;


SELECT v.*
INTO #tmp_contracts
FROM (
  VALUES

  (1, 123, 12345, 123456, 99999, 88888),
  (2, 123, 12345, 123456, 99999, 88888),
  (3, 123, 12345, 123456, 99999, 88888)

)v([Договор], [Свод0], [Отделение], [Участок], [Продавец], [Грузоотправитель])

SELECT *
FROM #tmp_contracts f
     JOIN dbo.Договор dog ON dog.row_id = f.Отделение;
```

Comment: Пример вставки добавлен просто для примера. Заполняться таблица будет отдельной процедурой. Очистка таблицы вынесена в процедуру cleartable, просто для удобства использования.

Comment: То есть запрос на самом деле вида INSERT #tmp_contracts EXEC MyProc? Это, конечно, все меняет

Comment: Просто не указывайте список полей при вставке.

Comment: в коде процедуры заполняется таблица.